# alternate approach of binary serialization/de-serialization

Tags: c#, .net, performance, serialization

Is it possible to convert a list of object directly to byte[] (and vice versa) to gain performance (by avoiding serialization/de-serialization)?

What I have in mind is that a list is somewhere in memory(heap). If I could read the bytes in heap for my list I could just assign it a variable (of byte[]) in my program. Is it possible? and if yes, how would I get back the original list from byte[] without de-serializing using BinaryFormatter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The .NET heap is an object graph, only blittable types will have a contiguous memory block for you to scrape. If you pinned an object and everything it referenced, and everything that stuff referenced recursively pinning the entire object graph you wanted to serialize, then you could start walking the object graph scraping it all into a contiguous byte array logically. Without pinning, the GC would move those objects around so you wouldn't be able to follow their memory links to know where to scrape data from the memory.

But this really wouldn't help you any because you'd be scraping objects that have pointers to memory addresses, and to reconstruct the object graph you'd have to reuse those exact memory addresses for all the pointers to line up - you have no way of knowing if those memory addresses would be available at another time. Alternatively you'd have to dig into the memory space of those objects; identify the pointer members and alter the addresses they pointed at to point them to where you construct their related nodes. This would be an absolute metric ton of work just to avoid serialization which is considerably less work and less dangerous.

Comment: Hmmmmm, Thanks a lot for the help. I am still looking for a fastest approach to get my list back from byte[].

Comment: What are you trying to say with that sentence about boxed types? Because a boxed struct can still contain fields of reference types, which can't be directly saved. Did you mean to say “[blittable types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75dwhxf7)” instead of “boxed types”?

Comment: @svick yes I'm aware; I thought about qualifying the statement but I figured for the purposes of this answer the detail about value types holding references wasn't necessary and might just confuse the larger problems with memory scraping an object graph in .NET. Edit it in if you disagree, I'm still on the fence about whether it belongs so I don't mind either way. Also thanks for giving me a new term for my lexicon, never heard of blittable types. I think using that term here though would only further confuse the already complex nature if this information.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa I think you should change it to blittable, if I understand what you're saying correctly. (You're saying that the primitive types like `int` are contiguous, but objects aren't since they could point to other places, right?) As I understand "boxed" types, those are primitive types which have been wrapped in objects, which seems to be trending towards the opposite of what you're going for.